# How to make the building of 3D tile in cesium be 3D？

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I'm trying to put the geojson file into the 3d tile in [cesium](https://cesium.com/), but after the conversion, the building is not 3d but flat, I would like to ask if there is a problem in which part?

This is my code：

```js
var tileset = viewer.scene.primitives.add(new Cesium.Cesium3DTileset({
    url: './tilesets/taichung_house/tileset.json'
}));
    
viewer.zoomTo(tileset, new Cesium.HeadingPitchRange(0, -0.5, 0));
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! please share a relevant piece of `tilesets/taichung_house/tileset.json` file